# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "kindle://home" - error: "(null)"

Tags: ios, sdk, google-analytics

После обновления до iOS9 и xCode7 столкнулась с проблемой: теперь не работает реклама и аналитика от Google. Хотя вроде работает, но при загрузке приложение немного подвисает, после чего отвисает и дальше работает как обычно. При этом выводит следующие ошибки:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "kindle://home" - error: "(null)"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "itms-books://" - error: "(null)"

VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:517): Saved hit: {
parameters =     {
    "&_crc" = 0;
    "&_s" = 85;
    "&_u" = ".etno";
    "&_v" = "mi3.1.2";
    "&a" = 1374537206;
    "&aid" = "ru.Camera";
    "&an" = ViewScanner;
    "&ate" = "<null>";
    "&av" = "1.0.4";
    "&cd" = MainScreen;
    "&cid" = "1c4139eb-cdff-41a2-974c-44bb4957ba63";
    "&dm" = "iPhone7,2";
    "&ds" = app;
    "&idfa" = "<null>";
    "&sr" = 750x1334;
    "&t" = screenview;
    "&tid" = "UA-63007191-5";
    "&ul" = "ru-ru";
    "&v" = 1;
    "&z" = 9418105402597233659;
    gaiVersion = "3.12";
};
timestamp = "2015-09-22 14:57:08 +0000";
}
2015-09-22 17:57:08.660 Camera[3189:790725] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 __70-[GAIBatchingDispatcher checkIAdCampaignAttributionWithHitParameters:]_block_invoke (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:749): iAd campaign tracking disabled because the iAd framework is not linked. See http://goo.gl/426NGa for instructions.
```

Статей с такими проблема находила много, но не нашла ни одного решения.. Единственное что было предложено, это добавить в info.plist:
LSApplicationQueriesSchemes и добавить туда kidle и itms-books. Но это не помогает...

Каково же решение этой проблемы?

Comment: Не может оно быть связано с App Transport Security?

Comment: Уже добавлено в NSAppTransportSecurity - NSAllowsArbitraryLoads - YES...

Comment: Еще пару вопросов: работает ли оно на iOS8? И какая именно реклама используется? AdMob, IMA или что то другое?

Comment: Реклама adMob, после обновлений не работает ни на одной операционной системе, на всех одинаково тупит.

Comment: Ошибку выдаваемую Google Analitics исправила (немного исправила код). И ошибка itms-books больше не выдается, но по прежнему остался в логе kindle://home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Говорят надо Enable Bitcode в NO выставить в настройках билда. Многим помогает (но мне не помогло, сам ищу ответ на данный вопрос). Ибо фреймворк гугла пытается каждые 2 минуты достучаться до этого киндл хоум и у меня сильно тормозит игра из-за этого в течении 5-6 секунд. (на уйстройстве с айос8 такого нет).

Comment: Самое верное решение вроде это обновить гугл мобайл сдк https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/rel-notes#ios

Comment: Обновление библиотеки Google это решение! Теперь проблем нет. Жаль только что sdk свой они обновили так поздно и отняли столько времени на поиски решения этой проблемы...

Answer (score -1):

В iOS 9 изменилось поведение метода canOpenURL:. Теперь необходимо объявлять список схем, которые используются для перехода в сторонние приложения. Это делается с помощью ключа LSApplicationQueriesSchemes в файле Info.plist. Попробуйте добавить следующий текст в Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>kindle</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Если вы читали мой вопрос, то должны были заметить, что я это уже пробовала и это не помогает